# Resizing 2 dependent bootstrap columns with jQuery - getting my math wrong?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple bootstrap layout with 2 column (4:8).
[image: Screenshot of layout]
 I want to make the columns *resizable*, so I used `jquery.resize()` for that with some [initial success](https://jsfiddle.net/m0x5aue8/).

However when I drag the resize handle left or right (the red bar) the dependent column grows/shrinks at a slower pace than the "master" column. I must be missing something.

I created a [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0x5aue8/) that shows the effect. Note: you need to make the output window wide so the columns show next to each other.

My questions:

- How can I resize the columns "in sync" so the blue and red line stay aligned
- when dragging to the right, the column extends the screen width, how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0x5aue8/1/)

I have added `$(masterDrag).css({left:'0px'});` in the resize event.