# Resizing 2 dependent bootstrap columns with Angular (2)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap layout with 2 column (4:8).
[image: Screenshot of layout]
 I want to make the columns *resizable* in tandem with each other.

After solving the [challenge with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071621/resizing-2-dependent-bootstrap-columns-with-jquery-getting-my-math-wrong) I'd like to use AngularJS (preferably 2). I found a sample for [a single box](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular2-resizable/demo/) (and [its source](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular2-resizable)), but wonder what a good Angular2 component approach would be:

- create 2 components and use glue code to resize them
- create 1 component with 2 columns (and 2 areas to fill content in)

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - not at the point yet. I tried to solicit input what might be better 1 or 2 components and then will try based on the recommendation